# Requiring In Classes in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to require in some classes in Node, but I require them in through a single file which holds an object of all the individual requires. Like so -

**File: /classes/controller.js**

```
module.exports = class Controller {}
```

**File: /classes/model.js**

```
module.exports = class Model {}
```

**File: /classes/classes.js**

```
module.exports = {
    Controller: require('./controller.js'),
    Model: require('./model.js')
}
```

Then in **app.js**

```
const classes = require('./classes/classes.js');
....code.....
....more code.....
const someController = new classes['Controller'];
```

The thing is, this works just fine - but only for the first file that requires in the 'classes' variable. Any subsequent files that need to also require 'classes' in, ends up holding only an empty object inside of the 'classes' variable (and no, the actual variable name does not matter, as I tried using a different variable name in the second file but it still wound up storing an empty object). For instance, I often need my Controller to implement a Model class.

So once app.js calls controller.js, inside of that -

**File: /classes/controller.js**

```
const classes = require('./classes.js');

module.exports = class Controller {
    constructor(var) {}

    someMethod() {
        ....code....
        const someModel = classes['Model'];
    }
}
```

I can call a 'console.log(classes)', and it will print out '{}', but again this is only if it is done inside of 'controller.js' and only after being called from inside of 'app.js'. It will print out all of the classes as expected if the 'console.log()' is done either inside of 'app.js', or if 'controller.js' is called directly instead of through 'app.js'. Which is how I know where/how the error is occurring. The specific error being thrown is -

```
classes.Model is not a constructor
```

So that is where my question/problem comes in, because as I said I have called other objects in multiple files without ever running into this problem. So it must have something to do with how classes are implemented, correct? And although I do not understand the specifics of how it works, I roughly know that when a file is required in, in Node, after that it uses that same reference for any subsequent files - correct? So I was thinking it must somehow be the interplay of those two things, but I have no idea after that fact nor if I am even correct in assuming that is the problem.

Comment: Empty objects returned from `require()` are often a sign of circular dependencies where module A requires B and module B requires A.  You can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like classes.js requires controller.js, and controller.js requires classes.js. That would be your circular dependency problem as mentioned above.

Comment: I appreciate the help and feedback, please see my comment on jfriend00's answer as to why I am not so sure this is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency of `require()` statements.  This causes one of the `require()` to just return an empty object.  You can't do that.

Inside of controller.js, you have `require('./classes.js');`.

Inside of classes.js, you have `require('./controller.js')`.

So, each refers to the other which is what causes the circular dependency.

You will need to restructure the way code is laid out into files so you don't have this.  Sometimes, the simplest fix is to just combine a couple functions into one file rather than having them all in separate files that are vulnerable to this issue.  I don't quite understand your overall design to know what best to suggest in this case.

If nobody else besides controller.js is really going to use classes.js, then you can just move that code into controller.js (where you don't need to require in controller.js any more).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate the feedback. You do point out a problem with my code, especially since I use this structure in multiple places throughout this code base. I do need to fix these circular dependencies regardless of whether this is the problem or not.

That being said, I'm not sure that is the problem here. I say that because you can leave the code exactly the same, but if you call 'controller.js' directly it works just fine - circular dependency and all. This seems to point to some interplay between how Node passes/references 'required' statements and how classes work.

Comment: @zentao - The FIRST thing to do is to get rid of the circular dependency.  Then, and only then, can you see if you also have some other problem.  You definitely have a circular dependency.  When you have that, it gives you an empty object for whatever `require()` causes the circular dependency (the one that comes 2nd) and that matches your symptoms exactly.  There is no evidence so far that this has something to do specifically with classes.  There is plenty of evidence that you are suffering from a circular dependency.  Get rid of that and then see what issue is next (if any).

Comment: @zentao - If you want me to comment on the "call `controller.js` directly comment" which I have no idea what that means, you'd have to show the exact code you're talking about.  Chances are you're just loading it at a different time (sometime after module load) and thus it avoids the circular dependency because both modules are already loaded so it just comes from the cache and circular references will actually work after each module is loaded - they won't work when the modules are being loaded for the first time - which is not something you should code for, just something to understand.

Comment: I think you hit on something there but I am having a hard time connecting the actual dots myself - loading it at a different time. When ```app.js``` calls ```controller.js```, then if you insert a ```console.log(classes)``` inside of ```controller.js``` it will print out ```{}```. But what I meant by call ```controller.js``` directly is, call it directly from the cli, that same ```console.log(classes)``` will print out the full ```classes``` object. Sorry if I am still not communicating clearly what I mean. If you need me to, I will throw some full code up and show exactly what I mean.

Comment: @zentao - There is no need.  Just fix your circular dependency.   It's causing your primary problem.  Whether or not there is another problem behind it, I have no idea but we can't tell until you fix the first roadblock.  I'm happy to participate in helping you fix your circular dependency, but not interested in speculating about some other problem until you fix this one first as that would most likely be a wild goose chase.  Your `console.log()` that prints out `{}` is proof enough that the circular dependency is causing you a problem.  You have to fix it first.

Comment: You are right. I just realized that even when it did print out the full classes object, the classes I was referencing were still empty objects. It is just that the other objects were not empty yet (basically, I saw 'something' and thought everything was fine without fully inspecting what was being shown) though they would be had they also been called later on. Which is exactly what is happening with app.js > controller.js. I really appreciate your help, I hope you don't think I was doubting your expertise/advice I just didn't fully understand what was going on. Thanks again!